# Unable to start a node manager on master

Tags: hadoop, centos, hadoop-yarn

I am setting up a Hadoop YARN cluster and I am using a machine as both a master and a slave. When I start the YARN using the following command, it starts the nodemanager on slaves but not on the master node.

```
sbin/yarn-daemons.sh start nodemanager
```

I have a master which also is slave and then I have another two slaves within the cluster, the nodemanagers in the slaves are starting properly.

The error I get :

```
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:8040] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
```

**Output  of some of the Commands .**

```
cat /etc/services | grep 8040
ampify          8040/tcp                # Ampify Messaging Protocol
ampify          8040/udp                # Ampify Messaging Protocol

lsof -i tcp:8040
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    28021   df  195u  IPv6 3580602      0t0  TCP server1.mydomain.com:ampify (LISTEN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the default configuration that Hadoop ships, port 8040 is the port that the NodeManager uses for the localizer.  This is basically a server endpoint responsible for bringing the files required to run a container onto the local node.  (For example, this can be a MapReduce job's jar file or distributed cache files.)

Assuming that there is another server on the machine (here shown as Ampify) legitimately bound to port 8040, and you don't want to stop that service, then it is possible to reconfigure the port used by the NodeManager for the localizer.  Set property `yarn.nodemanager.localizer.address` in your yarn-site.xml file.  This is documented here:

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

Pulling that from the XML source in the Hadoop tree, here is the documentation for the property:

```
<property>
  <description>Address where the localizer IPC is.</description>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.localizer.address</name>
  <value>${yarn.nodemanager.hostname}:8040</value>
</property>
```

Comment: I killed the service/process on 8040 and still get the same error , looks like the node manager is getting started twice , or is it the case that since this machine is also running the resource manager and resource manager also runs on 8040 ?

Comment: That's strange.  If no other process is bound to 8040 when you start NodeManager, then I wouldn't expect to see the error.  ResourceManager doesn't bind to 8040, at least not in the default configuration.  Have you tried setting yarn.nodemanager.localizer.address to a different port in your yarn-site.xml?  If that works, then that might narrow down the cause of the problem.

Comment: I did not change the property ,as I did not want to change the default behavior, I ll change it and try now though.

Comment: Chris thank for your hint , however looks like if you run the resource manager and the node manager on the same machine they end up using the same ports as specified here in the link. http://milinda.pathirage.org/hadoop/yarn/2013/09/29/how-to-setup-multi-node-hadoop-20xyarn-cluster.html , I gave seperate ports for each as specified in that document and now the nodemanager starts on the same machine as the resource manager for one of the three nodes, thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link.  FWIW, this won't happen under a default configuration.  The default is for ResourceManager to bind to port 8032, so I don't expect anyone to run into this conflict unless they manually reconfigure yarn.resourcemanager.address to use port 8040.

Comment: Chris, that is correct , I just realized that I had chosen 8040 for the resource manager i.e manually updated the yarn-site.xml, are you suggesting if I leave everything as default then I should be able to run both the resource manager and the node manager on the same machine ?

Comment: Slightly off topic , but why would resource manager show up as Ampify in the port scanning command output ?

Comment: Yes, if you leave yarn.resourcemanager.address out of your yarn-site.xml, then your ResourceManager will pick up the default port of 8032.  I expect the default port configuration will allow you to run ResourceManager and NodeManager on the same host.  Your /etc/services file has associated port 8040 with ampify.  I don't know anything about ampify, but I assume it's something that generally listens on 8040.  The lsof command is just blindly mapping the port number to the name identified in /etc/services.  It's not aware of the actual protocol, so it doesn't know that this is really YARN.

Comment: Chris, if I leave the default settings what should I specify in the yarn-site.xml in teh slave nodes , should I just leave out  the resource manager address properties in the yarn-site.xml for the default bindings to occur ? Thanks.

Comment: There is one more complication in that the default RM address is 0.0.0.0:8032.  That's fine if you're running everything on one node, but for a distributed environment, you need to tell all of the NodeManagers the one and only host for the ResourceManager.  You will in fact need to put `yarn.resourcemanager.address` in your yarn-site.xml, set to something like `rm.mydomain.com:8032`, whatever your hostname is.  (Thanks for asking.  I had forgotten about this part in my last response.)

Comment: Thanks is that(yarn.resourcemanager.address)  the only property that I would need to set in the slaves?

Answer (score 0):

Above error means, you are trying to start a process on 8040, which is already occupied by another instance.

To get rid of this error, you need to kill the process which is currently listening to port 8040. Your lsof  output says pid is 28021. kill the process using the following command and start again

```
kill -9 28021
```

Comment: I killed it still get the same error , looks like the node manager is getting started twice , or is it the case that since this machine is also running the resource manager and resource manager also runs on 8040 ?