# NodeManager and ResourceManager is not running

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-10.04, hadoop-yarn

I new to Hadoop programming. I have installed Hadoop and configured single cluster following this  [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-on-ubuntu-13-10)

NameNode and DataNode is running properly and I am able to copy file on HDFS. I can see these files through Web UI of HDFS. But unable to start yarn (start-yarn.sh). In the log following error is shown:

```
2014-11-16 08:52:37,716 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl failed in state STARTED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:8040] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:8040] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.getServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.HadoopYarnProtoRPC.getServer(HadoopYarnProtoRPC.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.YarnRPC.getServer(YarnRPC.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.createServer(ResourceLocalizationService.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStart(ResourceLocalizationService.java:261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceStart(ContainerManagerImpl.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(NodeManager.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:404)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:8040] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:719)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.<init>(Server.java:561)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.<init>(Server.java:2167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.<init>(RPC.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server.<init>(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:505)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.getServer(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Builder.build(RPC.java:742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.createServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.getServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:132)
    ... 13 more
2014-11-16 08:52:37,717 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 48181
2014-11-16 08:52:37,725 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 48181
2014-11-16 08:52:37,725 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2014-11-16 08:52:37,727 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service NodeManager failed in state STARTED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:8040] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:8040] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.getServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.HadoopYarnProtoRPC.getServer(HadoopYarnProtoRPC.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.YarnRPC.getServer(YarnRPC.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.createServer(ResourceLocalizationService.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStart(ResourceLocalizationService.java:261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceStart(ContainerManagerImpl.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(NodeManager.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:404)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:8040] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:719)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.<init>(Server.java:561)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.<init>(Server.java:2167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.<init>(RPC.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server.<init>(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:505)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.getServer(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Builder.build(RPC.java:742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.createServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.getServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:132)
    ... 13 more
```

This error suggests conflict in port. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153240/unable-to-start-a-node-mamager-on-master) suggest a solution by [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153240/unable-to-start-a-node-mamager-on-master) which looks will solve thee problem. In this post one link is given for complete step but looks not a complete [link](http://milinda.pathirage.org/hadoop/yarn/2013/09/29/how-to-setup-multi-node-hadoop-20xyarn-cluster.html)

Please suggest step to resolve port conflict

Answer (score 0):

" java.net.BindException: Address already in use" is the error. Is your 8040 port free? Seems something is using this port. If something else is running try changing the port and it should work.

Comment: After changing it is giving other error. It seems Yarn itself using same port for running 2 managers. There is no program running in 8940. It must be known problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use correct port for resource manager.
refer here
http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDP2Alpha/index.htm#Appendix/Ports_Appendix/YARN_Ports.htm