# services messed now when trying to start hdfs, nodemanager cannot be brought up

Tags: hadoop

I am doing some hadoop practice on my local VMware, 12GB RAM, 2CPU, 20GB disk space.

For unknown reason, my master node is having the following issue now:
1. I manually started NameNode, DataNode, ResourceManager, NodeManager.
2. I checked with jps to confirm every service is up, so far so good.
3. I tried to start the last piece Job History Server, no error reported
BUT, when I check with jps, I don't see the NodeManager, it simply disappeared!

[image]

So I tried to bring the NodeManager up again:

[image]

You can see there is no error reported but the NodeManager is not up.

I wonder if I can find any clue in log, here is the log screenshot:

[image]

Another log:

[image]

I don't see any clue in both the two logs.

Can anyone enlighten me on this? Thank you very much. Any clue is appreciated.

Comment: Is anything running on port 8040? Have you try this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153240/unable-to-start-a-node-manager-on-master

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see what caused the NodeManager to stop. Check for the log and see the time when it was stoped, that may give more info.

Also the open file limit may be low based on the ulimit -a in the output it is set to 1024.